# Cargar Data en Popup al momento de hacer clic en un enlace

Tags: javascript, foundation, asp.net-mvc-4

Estimados, mi problema es el siguiente, estoy desarrollando un modulo en .net mvc4, con foundation framework. Necesito realizar lo siguiente: mostrar una tabla, que muestra un consolidado de datos de personas(Jefes), al hacer clic en el nombre de la persona, despliega un popup con los detalles de funcionarios(delegados del jefe seleccionado).
hasta el momento tengo la tabla con el consolidado, el popup y la data a mostrar en el popup, pero mi problema es que no se si existe la manera para realizar la busqueda de datos al presionar en un nombre de persona(Jefes)y estos, visualizarlos en el popup (por el momento, tengo la carga de los detalles de funcionarios al iniciar la carga completa del modulo)

**Columna de tabla que invoca el PopUp**

```
<td><center><a data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" data-id="@item.JefedeVentas" href="btnJefe_0" id="DetalleEjecutivo_0" title="@item.JefedeVentas">@item.JefedeVentas</a></center></td>
```

**Ventana modal**

```
<div id="divModalLead" class='reveal-modal' data-reveal aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
    <a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

**Contenido a mostrar en modal** (necesito que esto se ejecute al momento de hacer clic en el nombre de ejecutivo, no al momento de cargar el modulo)

```
<fieldset id="DetalleEjecutivo_0" class="panel callout large-12">
    <h4>Ejecutivos por Jefe de venta</h4>
    <hr />

            <div id="divReporte" style="float:left; max-width:100%; overflow-x:auto!important; white-space:nowrap;">

                @Html.Action("Ejecutivos", "ReporteVentas", new { parDesde = desde, parhasta = hasta, parAño = agno })

            </div>

</fieldset>
```

**script JS**

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#DetalleEjecutivo_0").fadeOut(); //oculta el modal al iniciar

 $("#btnJefe_0").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var content = $("#DetalleEjecutivo_0").html();
            $('#divModalLead').html('<a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>');
            $('#divModalLead').append(content);
            $('#divModalLead').foundation('reveal', 'open'); //despliega modal en div 'divmodallead'
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Crea un PartialView, crea un método PartialViewResult en el controller que consulte ese reporte por el id que quieras y lo consumes con $.ajax al momento de hacer clic en el botón deseado

Comment: @DanAlvarez la llamada del .ajax en que momento se debe hacer? se puede incrustar dentro del clic function que tengo actualmente? lo siento, soy muy nuevo con ajax y js

Comment: si, puedes ponerlo ahi `$("#btnJefe_0").click(function (e) {e.preventDefault(); $("#idDivLoad").load('path/to/partialview',{id:$(this).attr('data-id')},function(){});....modal...........`

Comment: @DanAlvarez perfecto! realice lo que me recomendaste y conseguí el objetivo que necesitaba, de haber sido respuesta te hubiera dado mis puntos...pero muchas gracias!

Comment: gracias, pero luego los moderadores se ponen sus moños